# Syntax Error when Colon used in String Input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I receive a syntax error when using a colon within a string, but only as input.

```
>>> x = input('File Path: ')
File Path: C:\Users\Me\Documents

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    x = input('File Path: ')
  File "<string>", line 1
    C:\Users\Me\Documents
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've also tried as bellow, just in case escape characters are causing problems. No change.

```
File Path: C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents
```

Normally I'd push the string through something like this:

```
x = str(r'C:\Users\Me\Documents')
```

But assigning it without the `r` works just fine. The error only shows up when using the 
`x = input('  ')`
. I've also tried `x = str(input('  '))` Again, no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) tries to evaluate the string as though it were Python code.  You need to use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead if you just want the text entered.

Comment: First taught with Py3.X. Some little things like this I still miss. Thanks!